# Passing function to innerHTML method

Tags: javascript, html, function, output, innerhtml

Hi guys very new to JS and i've been working on this simple thing for too long trying to understand JS basics. Please help me out;

I have an empty H1 element that I want to fill with content using JavaScript.

I want the H1 header to contain a name from the array and display the "Hello" message.

What I want is something like:

innerHTML = greet(names[0]) for the H1 header. Im missing something trivial in understand how this is working any help would be appreciated.

```
names = ["Jan", "Klaas", "Piet"];
name = namen;



function greet(name){

console.log("Hallo " + name.toLowerCase());
}

document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = greet(names[0]);
```

document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = greet(names[0]); returns as "Undefined" in the H1 Element

Comment: console.log() prints value . it  doesnt return any value;

Comment: You should use `return` instead.

Comment: what is namen? Also return some value in the function greet like 

return name.toLowerCase();

Answer (score 3):

As of now you are not returning anything from you method thus getting `undefined`,
You need to `return` value from the method.

```
function greet(name){
  return "Hallo " + name.toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The function should return the string.

```
function greet(name){
   return "Hallo " + name.toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things to sort out here. You dont appear to be using the namen variable so remove the second line.

You could also declare the variable names when assigning it a value.

The greet function needs to return a value rather than log to console.

```
var names = ["Jan", "Klaas", "Piet"];

function greet(name){
return "Hallo " + name.toLowerCase();
}

document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = greet(names[0]);
```

see the codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KWNjYy)

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the string, like this:

```
names = ["Jan", "Klaas", "Piet"];

function greet(name){
    return ("Hallo " + name.toLowerCase());
}

document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = greet(names[0]);
```

`console.log()` logs the string in the browser console in the Developer Tools (shown by pressing F12). You need to `return` the value to assign it to the `innerHTML`, like i've shown above.

You also don't need to do the assignment `name = namen`, because `name` is just an alias for the value `names[0]` that you're passing into the function `greet()`. If you're doing this for use elsewhere then you'd be better off using a different variable name than `name` because otherwise this will cause confusion later on and potential conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `"name=namen"`.

You have to return some values from function.